# jquery do action unless div already exists, then replace

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a jquery datatable and in that datatable each row has a column that lets you view the details of the row. I don't need the datatables row_details thing.

The idea is that, once a 'view' is clicked, the text changes to hide, and a div with row_### is append to the content body.  then, if the same button is clicked while that row is showing, it hides it. also, if if someone clicks view for another row, the previous row text should change back to hide, the div hidden, and that row that was just clicked should be displayed.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$("a[class^=view]").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('class').match(/\d{1,}/);

    if( $("div[id^=report_]").size() >= 1) {
     // Slide up, remove
             // Change text back to view    
    } else {
             // Append and change text to Hide
            }
});
```

If I click another 'view' when details for one is already showing, it adds a new div inside the current div AND appends the same new div to the content body.. obviously not the effect I'm looking for so somewhere my logic is wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: You shouldn't be using `size`, it's deprecated. Use the `length` property like `if ( $("div[id^=report_]").length ) { ... }`

Comment: You can replace `/\d{1,}/` with `/\d+/`

Comment: It's like this:

1) If no element exists, append it and change text to "Hide"
2) If that same "View" link is clicked, remove element and change text back to view.
3) If an element exists, remove that element and change its related text back to view, while appending a new one and changing its text to hide.  I get the adding/removing thing, but when I append the new div it gets removed automatically since its in the same conditional that checks for more than 0 elements of class^=report_

Comment: is this close to what you want...spec is still unclear  http://jsfiddle.net/Jt45Y/

Answer (score 0):

Got it. A bit messy, but it works.  Interested if there is another way. Here's the solution:

```
$("a[class^=view]").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('class').match(/\d+/);

    if($(this).text() == "Hide") {
        $(this).text("View");
        $("#report").html(null);
    } else {
        $("a[class^=view_]").each(function(){$(this).text("View");});
        $(this).text("Hide");
        $("#report").html("<div id='report_"+id+"'>viewing report "+id+"</div>").slideDown();
    }
});
```

Comment: if you want prior ones removed will need to change text of prior button's that were activated also.. can add an 'active' class to buttons and make it easy to find prior one

Answer (score 0):

To know if an element already exist i use jquery's find on the parent element, looking for his child... like so:

```
if($('#parent_container').find('#child_element').length>0){
     //element(s) exists
}else{
     //element(s) not found
}
```